# Calculation over multiple vector layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, field-calculation

I have a few points as a layer. Then I have another layer with the same points but with different values. For example:

Layer A: Time: 5 [hours]

Layer B: Time: 4 [hours]

Is there a QGIS function that calculates the difference between these values? Something like the raster calculator but for vector layers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
"layer_a_attr" - overlay_intersects('Layer B',"layer_b_attr")[0]
```

in [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?#using-the-field-calculator) of `Layer A`. Make sure the points do indeed really intersect, if they dont do, you can add a small buffer. The index bracket `[0]` is needed because there may be more than one intersecting point and therefore `overlay_intersect()` returns an array. `[0]` returns the first value of the array. `overlay_intersects()` is available since QGIS 3.16. For earlier versions [you could use `aggregate()` function instead](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/418889/107424).

As [suggested by @Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418866/calculation-over-multiple-vector-layers-in-qgis/418889#comment682084_418867), you can also use `overlay_nearest('Layer B',"layer_b_attr",max_distance:=50)[0]` instead of a buffer, which shortens the expression and is easier to handle.

Comment: Use `overlay_nearest` with `limit:=1` to cover cases where points do not intersect perfectly. That means that every point is calculated with its nearest neighbor.

Comment: Yes, overlay functions always return an array, this time with just one element, thus get this (as in your case) with `[0]` at the end. So the whole expression looks like: `"your field" - overlay_nearest('Layer B',"your field", limit:=1)[0]` - maybe you want to add this to your solution.

Comment: You might want to add a `max_distance` argument to `overlay_nearest` to be sure to only capture points within a certain (very small) distance from the point - corresponding to the buffer in your proposal.

Comment: How would the "aggregate" function work? I have a lower version than 3.16 and due to some issues I cannot update qgis for this problem. I thought about: ```aggregate(layer:='Layer B',expression:="my field", filter:=(intersects('Layer A','Layer B')))``` I cant imagine any aggregate which includes this case

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it with versions earlier than QGIS 3.16 using [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate):

```sql
"layer_a_attr" 
-
array_first(
 aggregate(
  layer:='Layer B',
  aggregate:='array_agg',
  expression:="layer_b_attr",
  filter:=intersects($geometry,buffer(geometry(@parent),50))
 )
)
```

Note that these versions also do not support index brackets, so we use `array_first()` instead of `[0]`. Instead of an array you could also return a concatenated string or what you like (see [the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate)). Insert this into the [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?#using-the-field-calculator) of `Layer A`. If you only want exact matches you can remove the buffer. Buffer distance is in CRS units of `Layer A`. Make sure both layers are in the same CRS.